# Escolher pasta com mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como eu faço para o usuário poder escolher a pasta em que vai gravar uma planilha? A chamada será a partir de uma view razor do mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível selecionar a pasta de um site usando HTML native + JS. Você só pode selecionar um arquivo ou lista de arquivos para upload, mas não uma pasta em si. Normalmente você nem vai conseguir ver o caminho original do arquivo que foi carregado, e você simplesmente não pode obter acesso direto ao sistema de arquivos do usuário. A comunicação da Web é baseada em solicitações HTTP e é stateless, portanto, não haveria como o servidor acessar a pasta no PC (remoto) do usuário. E por motivos de segurança, nem mesmo o JavaScript no cliente pode fazê-lo.

Comment: Como eu faço para gerar uma planilha na minha máquina com MVC?

Comment: Você pode pesquisar um pouco sobre o FileResult, ele vai atender o que você precisa! Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.